# Lightning input type search

Tags: lightning-aura-components, search

I have a custom lightning component where i use a

```
<lightning:input disabled="{!v.disabled}" aura:id="userinput" label="{!v.Label}" name="searchText" onchange="{!c.searchField}" onclick="{!c.getPickListValues}" value="{!v.selectRecordName}" isLoading="{!v.LoadingText}" type="search" fieldLevelHelp="{!v.helpText}" class="leftspace"/>
```

and sometimes i set the aura attribute v.disabled=true, in order to make the input field disabled. However, although it gets greyed out, i still can click the button (X) and it clears the input. I want to avoid this but i don't know which is the action i should look for... Any suggestions??[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aura:if to hide the button when the v.disabled=true

```
<aura:if isTrue={!v.disabled== true}>

you can add the code without close(x) option here.

<aura:set attribute = false>
<lightning:input disabled="{!v.disabled}" aura:id="userinput" label="{!v.Label}" name="searchText" onchange="{!c.searchField}" onclick="{!c.getPickListValues}" value="{!v.selectRecordName}" isLoading="{!v.LoadingText}" type="search" fieldLevelHelp="{!v.helpText}" class="leftspace"/>
</aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks:))

Answer (score 2):

Do validation on onclick of X icon. Like 
`if(cmp.get("v.disabled")==true)
{
    Don't delete the value in "v.selectRecordName"
}`